# Is 1 hour sufficient to transfer terminals at Changi airport?

Tags: transit, airport-transfer, singapore-airlines, sin

I am flying out of JFK and have a layover at Changi Airport/SIN. My JFK-SIN flight will arrive at SIN terminal 3 at 6:10 AM. My next flight will leave SIN from terminal 2 at 7:10 AM.

Will I have enough time to get from my gate at terminal 3 to my gate at terminal 2?

Comment: Is this booked as a sinlg eticket or two separate bookings?

Comment: If you are going from JFK to SIN, I can't understand why you need to transfer - you are at your destination already. Makes no sense.

Comment: @fabspro: It sounds to me like Changi/SIN is not OP's final destination.

Comment: @moonman239 looks that way after the recent edits to the question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is one hour good for transit time at Changi ?

It this is a single PNR/Ticket/Booking: yes. You have a high chance of making it and if, not, SQ will book you on the next available flight.

If there are two separate PNRs with a self connection: Absolutely not.

Every individual case is a little different: check here for details

- https://www.changiairport.com/en/airport-guide/transit.html
- https://www.singaporeair.com/en_UK/sg/travel-info/transit-through-singapore/

Comment: Single Ticket PNR / Booking on SQ.

Comment: What is a PNR??

Comment: @fabspro: PNR = Passenger Name Record. That's the 6-digit confirmation number that comes with the booking.

Comment: @Hilmar that would be an excellent bit of detail to include in the answer, instead of using jargon which is not understood by a layperson! Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 13):

Changi is an extremely efficient and easy to navigate airport. T2 and T3 are part of the same complex, and transferring between them should take no more than 20-30 minutes by the in terminal transit. Security is performed at the gate, so you won't need to clear security to enter the transfer area.

If the flight is being sold as a single ticket then it is very doable, but you might want to look up what time the next flight to your destination is, in the event you miss the connection.

However, this is far too short a time for a self transfer.

Comment: It's a single ticket. Next Flight is @ 0710

Comment: @wOSTA The next flight is 24h after your scheduled flight?

Comment: I think @wOSTA misunderstood. _His_ next flight is at 07:10, one hour after arrival (thus the concern about making the connection). The question in this answer was "what is the next available flight after that, in case you miss the connection". It's possible that this is a once per day flight...

Comment: I am sure there are multiple flights after this. I appreciate your replies